# Java how to get Class reference for a fuly parameterized GenericType<OtherType>

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to get a Class reference to a GenericType. Note that OtherType isn't just a place-holder - this is a fully parameterized type. And an example we could use List.

For a non-generic type I could do something like `Class c = String.class`

However if I try to do `Class c = List<String>.class` it doesn't compile....

How do I get a fully parameterized generic type Class reference?

EDIT: My goal is to use mokito to mock a TypedQuery for a unit test

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing. It is not possible.

Comment: Hmmm. How is it not possible to mock such a class then, such as with mokito? Trying to mock TypedQuery<T>

Comment: Mock the raw List and cast it

Comment: I'll try that thanks :)

Comment: Please show what you're actually trying to do, rather than how you're trying to solve it. (This is currently the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @AndyTurner I did ask about what I'm trying to do. Just a technical tid-bit.

Comment: @Michael - ty, I was able to use mock(TypedQuery.class) and that appears to have worked (at least there's no compile errors anymore, still debugging though)

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams not really, you've just sort of said "I'm trying to do something with Mockito for a unit test". If you show a [mcve] of the code you're trying to write, it's much easier to recommend an alternative.